# A line feed gets added in the "Let's Encrypt Challenge"

Tags: 7, ssl, acquia-cloud

I am using the [Let's Encrypt module](https://www.drupal.org/project/letsencrypt_challenge) for Drupal 7, trying to follow the instructions [outlined here by Redfin Solutions](https://redfinsolutions.com/blog/installing-free-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificates-acquia), to install free SSL on Acquia's servers, but I've run into a curious problem:

Each time I generate the challenge using the certbot manual mode (using `sudo certbot certonly --manual -d example.com`), It tells me the key authorization file from the server does not match the challenge.

> Failed authorization procedure. example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: The key authorization file from the server did not match this challenge
>   [TBgi6LPQfn7SJOTMcA67Crjrb_wGI9WKL4XAE-a17io.x6url1PIuenF6WDlPejYYJM2E4fg3wOFn8t4ghXDAGI] != [
>   TBgi6LPQfn7SJOTMcA67Crjrb_wGI9WKL4XAE-a17io.x6url1PIuenF6WDlPejYYJM2E4fg3wOFn8t4ghXDAGI]
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>
> - The following errors were reported by the server:
>     Domain: example.com
>     Type: unauthorized
>     Detail: The key authorization file from the server did not match    this challenge [TBgi6LPQfn7SJOTMcA67Crjrb_wGI9WKL4XAE-a17io.x6url1PIuenF6WDlPejYYJM2E4fg3wOFn8t4ghXDAGI] != [TBgi6LPQfn7SJOTMcA67Crjrb_wGI9WKL4XAE-a17io.x6url1PIuenF6WDlPejYYJM2E4fg3wOFn8t4ghXDAGI]
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain contain(s) the right IP address.

As you can see, the second one (which is the one in the server), shows with a linefeed at the start. I am baffled by this, I went into the module and it just displays the value saved in a system variable, which I verified in the database. Other than that they seem to be identical, I have not been able to go further. Has anybody experienced anything similar? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Update: I tried this in a different (simpler, non Aqcuia) instance, and the line feed does not show. Will try with a different Acquia site.

Comment: Update: Tested a different Acquia site and works without issue. The problem seems to be site specific.

Comment: Update: Problem seems theme related. Switched themes and problem goes away.

Comment: Finally: a file in the theme had a blank line, should be empty. Everything in order now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the module works like a charm, the problem was theme related, sending out a blank line at the top of the page: this was enough to confuse Let's Encrypt when running the validation of the site.